# how to send multipart/form-data in web services that c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman

how to read multipart/form-data in web services?
i am send data using postman body  form-data but postman is getting error.

```
    public class Api : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string Hell(string name)
        {
            return CommonUtilities.GetJSonSerialized(name);
        }
    }
```

> error  System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid:
>   multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary79Ky1A1Kfyyy7qUi.
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

that error have getting by postman.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQQvj.png)

Comment: Please post your postman request.

Comment: Post your web.config

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? And why are you using the obsolete ASMX stack instead of WCF? In any case SOAP works with POST and is *already handled* by the framework.

Comment: Are you trying to create a *REST* API? In that case you are using the wrong classes/APIs. ASMX never supported REST, it only provided limited AJAX support. WCF provided only rudimentary support as a stop-gap measure. To create a REST API in ASP.NET you should use ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: my requirement is create web service using ASMX.

Answer (score 0):

Asmx file can also be used for rest api creation (Which is not the recommended approach).

This can be achieved by the below code snippet.

```
[ScriptService]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Randezvous : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void getUnitPersonels(string user, string pass, decimal unitNo)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        #region ..:: Kullanıcı şİfre Kontrol ::..
        if (!(unit == "xxx" && pass == "yyy"))
        {

            string msg = "User or pass is wrong.";
            Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(msg));
            return;
        }
        #endregion

        List<Personels> personels = _units.getUnitPersonels(unitNo);

        string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(personels);
        Context.Response.Write(jsonString);
    }
}
```

You can test this code in c# with the code that is shown below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:18511/Randezvous.asmx/getUnitPersonels");
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
    query["unitNo"] = "0";
    builder.Query = query.ToString();
    string url = builder.ToString();

    var result = Task.FromResult(client.GetAsync(url).Result).Result.Content;
    var resultJson = result.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

}
```